# Py2exe; Import Error no module named colorama

Tags: python, installation, py2exe, importerror, colorama

My python script is using colorama module. So, I include it and try to compile but I get this error:

```
raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named colorama
```

My setup.py is this one:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import colorama

setup(console=['sniffer_4_0.py'],options={"py2exe": {'includes': ["email.utils", "colorama"]}})
```

I have seen someone who had the same problem (with another library, not colorama) and solved it by importing that library at the beggining of the script. So it's what I did, but I have the same error. Do you know why?

Thanks!
Maichel

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83588/discussion-on-question-by-maichel-py2exe-import-error-no-module-named-colorama).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to download colorama *.tar.gz from Python Package Index and instead of installing the package using colorama's setup.py script, simply to extract the colorama directory and put it inside your project's folder. There is no need to uninstall previously installed colorama package.